# Wordpress related products loop hide current product

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I am displaying latest products when viewing a certain product. When viewing the product it still appears as a "Recent product" at the bottom.

```
<ul class="products">
                <?php
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'product',
                    'posts_per_page' => 3,
                    'post__in' => $related,
                );
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
                    endwhile;
                } else {
                    echo __( 'No products found' );
                }
                wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
```

I tried using 'post__not_in' => array($product->id) , but it doesn't work.

How do I hide the product I am viewing from the recent products loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to declare `$product` as `global` but both of `global $post; $post->ID` and `global $product; $product->id` will work. Also, note about `post__not_in`

> If this is used in the same query as post__in, it will be ignored

You will need to remove your current product id from $related if it's there (and I assume it is) like so

```
$key=array_search($post->ID,$related);
//or
$key=array_search($product->id, $related);
if($key!==FALSE)
{
    unset($related[$key]);
}
```